# Intermittent SIGINTs on launch in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, ios-simulator, sigint

Occasionally when I run my app in the simulator, it freezes on startup with a `SIGINT`. The lines it breaks on are varied, but they include system library calls like `libsystem_c.dylib'pthread_rwlock_unlock$UNIX2003:` and calls in my own code like `self.view.layer.shadowRadius= 6.0f;` or `button= [[UIButton alloc] initWithImage:image];`. The behavior is unpredictable and I can't figure out what causes it. This doesn't happen on the device.

I do use `SIGINT` in my code occasionally to kill the app in debug builds if an assert fails, but this issue never happens on or near one of those lines.